# Convert varchar into datetime zone

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a column called `updated_at` which has datetime zone in varchar.

[image]

I would like to alter and convert the column into datetime zone in SQL Server. I referred to other posts but with no success

This is a sample row:

```
2022-09-23T11:35:21.469+01:00
```

Can anyone advise the SQL script for the above to convert the column into datetime zone in the table?

Comment: Please show your failed attempts

Comment: Please don't use images for data, use formatted text.

Comment: Those values don't have a "time zone" - they have a **UTC offset**. A UTC offset is not the same thing as a timezone (a timezone _has_ one-or-more UTC offsets (e.g. DST)).

Comment: `SELECT CONVERT( datetimeoffset(7), '2022-09-23T11:35:21.469+01:00' ) AS dto;` <-- This works fine for me.

Comment: @Dai Thanks. I need to change my entire existing column updated_at into datetime. However, when I tried this "Select CONVERT(datetimeoffset(7), updated_at) as dto, getting error. Can you advise?

Comment: What error? Please add that to your question-post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server supports converting ISO 8601 formatted date+time values to `datetimeoffset` using `CONVERT` - you should also specify `style: 127` ([which corresponds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to ISO 8601 formats) to ensure that SQL Server evaluates `CONVERT` in a deterministic fashion (for predictability, portability, and performance reasons).

To convert a column in an existing table you'll need to add a new `NULL`-able column first, populate it with the converted values and make it `NOT NULL`, then drop the old column. Use a `TRANSACTION` to be safe:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRANSACTION myTxn;

ALTER TABLE dbo.myTable
    ADD updated_at_dto datetimeoffset(7) NULL;

UPDATE
    dbo.myTable
SET
    updated_at_dto = CONVERT( datetimeoffset(7), updated_at, 127 );

ALTER TABLE dbo.myTable
    ALTER updated_at_dto datetimeoffset(7) NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE dbo.myTable
    DROP COLUMN updated_at;

EXEC sys.sp_rename @objname = N'dbo.myTable.updated_at_dto', @newname = 'updated_at', @objtype = 'COLUMN';

COMMIT TRANSACTION myTxn;
```